# problem with setting up Joomla on XAMMP

Tags: 13.04, xampp, joomla

i have Ubuntu 13.04 and i extracted Joomla on htdocs folder then i setup it 
after that i have to enter the Joomla administration panel and when i enter the default username (root) and without a password it gives me an error with connecting to database i searched the internet and they said the problem either in database username or password and mine doesn't have any password

anyone can help ??

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I did anything like that, but from memory XAMPP was a pain in the but to use on Linux and I ended up using Cherokee webserver instead:

http://cherokee-project.com/downloads.html

If you don't have any particular need to use XAMPP I'd recommend it. I found it powerful, but much more user friendly, and I was able to find videos on youtube to help me out with understanding the configuration concepts.